# How can I customize a UISwitch using my custom .png?

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0, ios4, uiswitch

So in my code I used the `setAlternateColor:` method on my UISwitch to change the color to orange but my app got rejected because of this.

So I decided to use photoshop to create a custom UISwitch. Now that I have the image how am I supposed to get the UISwitch to use my custom .png?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't. It's probably easiest to write your own custom switch class. It's not very hard to subclass `UIControl` and reimplement the few things `UISwitch` does. (I don't know if it would also work to subclass `UISwitch` directly and override `drawRect:`. Might be worth a try.)

Comment: In that case am I supposed to take care of drawing the shape and animating and everything in the drawRect method (i'm not that experienced as far as drawing goes)?

Comment: Yes, would have to draw everything.